# Pass custom value to the logger instead of to every message

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I want to log the user session. Currently the code is as follows (setting formatter and handlers is omitted):

```
logger = logging.getLogger("component")
logger.info("message", extra={"session": 123})
logger.debug("debug", extra={"session": 123})
```

If there are several messages to be logged, it's annoying to send this extra information each time. What would be the best/cleanest/most pythonic way to achieve something like that:

```
logger = logging.getLogger("component")
# for example:
logger.addExtra({"session": 123})
logger.info("message") # extra would be added automatically
logger.debug("debug") # extra would be added automatically
```

I could think of extending the logger and overriding logging methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `LoggerAdapter` as @DhruvPathak specified. According to [`LoggerAdapter`s signature](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.LoggerAdapter):

```
class logging.LoggerAdapter(logger, extra)
```

you do that by providing your logger instance and the `extra` args during initialization:

```
logger = logging.LoggerAdapter(logger, extra)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use function factories for instance like that

```
def get_logger_with_context(name, context=None):
    extra = context or {}
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)

    def log(level, message, **kwargs):
        getattr(logger, level)(message, extra=context)

    return log
```

Answer (score 1):

Such [custom logging](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#adding-contextual-information-to-your-logging-output) is feasible in python logging class, using logging.loggerAdapters which modify the logging behaviour.

> An easy way in which you can pass contextual information to be output
>   along with logging event information is to use the LoggerAdapter
>   class. This class is designed to look like a Logger, so that you can
>   call debug(), info(), warning(), error(), exception(), critical() and
>   log(). These methods have the same signatures as their counterparts in
>   Logger, so you can use the two types of instances interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Python logging doc](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#adding-contextual-information-to-your-logging-output): Beside the LogAdapter, you can use also the LogFilter.

I usually use [MDC](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html) since in influences all loggers. Unfortunately, the Python logging does not have MDC. I have just found the [mdaniel's MDC gist](https://gist.github.com/mdaniel/8347533).

Comment: That MDC gist seems to only work with static data because it's used as annotations. Is that right?

Comment: @z11i Just use `set_mdc`, `clear_mdc` from the code for dynamic data.